# Spring security custom login page throws 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying out a simple Spring Security Custom Login page sample but always ending up with a page not found 404 error in the browser. Will be pleased if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean:beans xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/events/" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/form" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login/form" 
                    login-processing-url="/login"
                    username-parameter="username"
                    password-parameter="password"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login/form?error"
                    default-target-url="/default"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1@example.com" password="user1" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</bean:beans>
```

mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
                           >

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springsec.config"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

registered the view with a view controller registry

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry v) {
        v.addViewController("/login/form").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

the login page,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="pageTitle" value="Please Login" scope="request"/>

<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>

<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            Failed to login.
            <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
                Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.
                                        message}" />
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input id="submit" class="btn" name="submit" type="submit"
               value="Login"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I remove the `<form-login>` tag in the security.xml the default login page is coming up and I can use the credentials and login, but the custom login page is ending up in a 404. Will be pleased with any suggestions/corrections.

Comment: Please show your ViewResolver configuration.

Comment: Sorry I've been trying all sorts of changes hence the ViewResolver is not in the xml file, Initially it had, error was same.

Comment: Please take note that when I remove the <form-login> tag from the Spring security.xml the spring default login page shows up. What are the things that I have to take care when adding the elements inside <form-login>  ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a view resolver configured, or it is not configured correctly. Because of this, Spring will look for login.jsp in the root of your src/main/webapp directory.

To set up a view resolver, add something like this to your mvc-config.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Using this example config Spring will look for your view in /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp

Change this according to your directory structure.

Comment: I have done that also, but it's the same, Is there anything wrong with the configuration/code?

Comment: If you don't use the ViewControllerRegistry, but create a separate controller for the login page, does it help?

Comment: Hi @Relevart, Is there a difference with the both methods, anyhow I have tried that too :(

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is almost two years old, I just spent way too much time jerking around with this myself with the Spring MVC 4.3.14 and Spring Security 4.2.4.  I don't think that the custom login page XML config in the Spring Security documentation is working as advertised.  Granted I'm far from a Spring expert.

Anyway, my config is similar to yours (and many others I read about in the last 24 hours).  A couple of possibly notable differences are my 'contextConfigLocation' setup in 'web.xml':

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and my http tag in 'security.xml':

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>
```

after setting this up, what finally resolved it for me was registering an implicit(?) controller for the custom login page in 'dispatcher-servlet.xml':

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="auth/login"/>
```

my 'login.jsp' for my project is in /WEB-INF/views/auth/, and I have a pretty standard view resolver setup:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

The Spring Security documentation custom login page example that I found didn't mention the implicit controller, but possibly it was somewhere else in the doc.

I found it in this tutorial:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Hopefully this helps out someone who finds it.